# Rails - view turning complete white after refreshed or visited several times

Tags: ruby-on-rails, safari, ruby-on-rails-4, erb, rails-activerecord

I have a view page that will randomly turn into a blank white page after I have visited it a few times.  If I change something in the view, it turns back to normal temporarily, but then after a few more page visits, the page turns white again.  Also, it only happens in Safari.  Here is the controller action for the page:

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
    def show_current_projects_to_freelancer
        if current_user.type == 'Student'
            @projects = current_user.projects
            @schedules = current_user.projects.collect {|project| project.schedule}
        else
            redirect_to applicants_path, notice: 'Only Freelancers have access to this page.'
        end
    end
end
```

There are two models: Schedule and Project. Schedule belongs_To Project and Project has_one schedule. The routes for schedule and Project are nested like this:

```
get 'projects/current', to: 'projects#show_current', as: :current_freelancer_projects
resources :projects do
      resources :schedules
end
```

I've changed my view several times.  This happens regardless of whether there is content in the view or no content.  Here is what the view looks like now:

```
<div style="color: black;">
<h3>Current freelancer Projects</h3>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Project Name</td>
            <td>Employer Name</td>
            <td>Date of Bid</td>
            <td>rating</td>
            <td>Bid</td>
            <td>Tags</td>
            <td>Make Schedule</td>
        </tr>
    <% @projects.each do |project| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= project.title %></td>
            <td><%= project.employer.email %></td>
            <td>date</td>
            <td>rating</td>
            <td>bid</td>
            <td>tags</td>
            <td><%= link_to 'Create Schedule', new_project_schedule_path(project.id, Schedule.new) %></td>
        </tr>
    <% end %>
    </table>
</div>
```

I can't imagine what is causing this.  I know it has to be independent from the view because no matter how i change the view it still happens.  Does anyone have any ideas?

Here are the logs when the page does not show up.  When the page does show up, its too long.

```
Started GET "/current" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 17:08:18 -0500
Started GET "/current" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-11-22 17:08:18 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (0.4ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
Processing by ProjectsController#show_current_projects_to_freelancer as HTML
Processing by ProjectsController#show_current_projects_to_freelancer as HTML
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 226 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  User Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 226 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Project Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 226]]
  Project Load (3.3ms)  SELECT "projects".* FROM "projects" WHERE "projects"."student_id" = $1  [["student_id", 226]]
  Employer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 202]]
  Employer Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 202]]
  Employer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  Employer Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  CACHE (0.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."type" IN ('Employer') AND "users"."id" = $1 ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["id", 201]]
  Rendered projects/show_current_projects_to_freelancer.html.erb within layouts/application (97.3ms)
  Rendered projects/show_current_projects_to_freelancer.html.erb within layouts/application (97.3ms)
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."student_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."state" = 'active'  [["student_id", 226]]
   (0.9ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "relationships" WHERE "relationships"."student_id" = $1 AND "relationships"."state" = 'active'  [["student_id", 226]]
  Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 226]]
  Profile Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE "profiles"."user_id" = $1 ORDER BY "profiles"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 226]]
  Rendered layouts/_ssi_header_inner.html.erb (69.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_ssi_header_inner.html.erb (69.1ms)
  Rendered layouts/_ssi_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
  Rendered layouts/_ssi_footer.html.erb (0.3ms)
Completed 200 OK in 547ms (Views: 384.9ms | ActiveRecord: 17.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 547ms (Views: 384.9ms | ActiveRecord: 17.2ms)
```

Comment: How many times are you going to ask this same question?

Comment: I learned so much after coding all day that the question is different form my other ones.  I don't think my older questions are relevant anymore because i was asking the wrong things.

Comment: Then you should mark your old questions as being resolved so that other users don't needlessly waste time answering them.

Comment: OK.  The thing is i've changed the view a ton of times. I even had a blank view for a while and this still happened.  I'll post what it looks like now though.

Comment: I'd recommend look at your log when this occurs, and paste the output for that request... See that it is loading the actual template.

Comment: @omarvelous, scratch that last comment.  I posted the logs that happen when it shows white.

Comment: What's odd.... is the request comes in twice and is processed twice... Never seen that before... What server are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure.   I'm using postgres database.  I'm using whatever server comes with rails.

Comment: Still struggling for an answer here? Have you considered that you're perhaps not asking the right question?

Comment: I'm having this same issue and haven't found a fix. It seems to be related to etags and page caching. I don't want to turn etags off entirely if I can help it.

Comment: Its a flaw in safari.  Disabling etags is the only thing I could figure out.  Try adding this code to your production.rb and development.rb files: ' config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag '

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was the cache.  By disabling the cache, I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: Philip, can you tell more about what exactly you did to resolve the issue? I have the same problem. Page loads blank and only browser restart helps.

Comment: put this in your production.rb file and development.rb file: "config.middleware.delete Rack::ETag"

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a WebKit bug; it's happening with a lot of people even in iOS. https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32829

Answer (score 0):

Actually the [linked Webkit bugreport](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=32829) is wrong, because it refers to a Server sending a 304 for an *unconditional request*, so this is actually bad behavior of the Server and no Webkit bug.

The Bug that shows up in Safari is that it sends a conditional request, the server responds correctly with a 304 and then Safari shows a white page, probably due to invalid Cache.
And I doubt this is a Webkit bug after all, since no other Browser is affected, at least what I managed to research so far I could only reproduce this in Safari.

I filed a radar on Apples Bugtracker ([rdar://19074069](http://openradar.appspot.com/19074069)), but if anyone can reproduce this with the Webkit browser, then this is more likely a Webkit bug, but I weren't able to do so.